# Probability distribution of the following form

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Is there any known probability distribution whose pdf is the following?

Given $y\in[0,1]$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $F(x)$, a CDF of some random variable $X$ (with density $f(x)$), $h(x)$ is given by
$$h(x)=(n+1)\sum^{n}_{k=0}{n\choose k}^2y^k(1-y)^{n-k}F(x)^k[1-F(x)]^{n-k}f(x)$$
$h(x)$ is a weighted average of pdf of $k$-th order statistics of $X$ with $n+1$ samples.

What I wonder is whether there's any known or famous random variable or associated probability distribution whose pdf is the same as $h(x)$.

Comment: Let $Y\sim B(n,y)$ be binomial r.v. independent on i.i.d.r.v.'s  $X_1,\ldots, X_{n+1}$, and $F$ ($f$) is CDF (pdf) of $X_i$. Then $h(x)$ is a pdf of $Y+1$st order statistics $X_{(Y+1)}$. I doubt that we can say anything more.

Comment: That seems to be a nice approach to explain $h$. Thanks! I also doubt that there's any known r.v. with $h$ as its pdf though..